# Unit testing with robolectric and mockito for retrofit in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit, robolectric

I am facing problem how to write test code for retrofit.The codes are as below.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;
import gallery.com.brandlistview.Bird;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class MainActivity implements Callback<List<Bird>> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Globals.getRestClient().getBirdClient().getBirdList(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(List<Bird> birds, Response response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(--------) {
    }
}
```

Bird.java

```
public class Bird {
    private String image_url;
    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }
    public void setImage_url(---------) {
        -----------
    }
}
```

Globals.java

```
public class globals{
    public static RestClient restClient;

    public static RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient; 
    }
    public static BirdClient getBirdClient() {
        return getRestClient().getBirdClient();
    }
}
```

RestClient.java

```
public class RestClient{
private BirdClient   mBirdClient;

public RestClient() {
   mBirdClient = new BirdClient(getBirdService());
}

public BirdClient getBirdClient() { return mBirdClient; }

public static BirdService getBirdService() {
   RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
         .setEndpoint(URL)
         .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
         .build();

   return restAdapter.create(BirdService.class);
}
}
```

BirdClient.java

```
public class BirdClient{
private BirdService mAPIService;

public BirdClient(BirdService service) {
   assert service != null;
   mAPIService = service;
}
public void getBirdList(final Callback<List<Bird>> delegate) {
  ----------------------
}
}
```

BirdService.java

```
public interface BirdService {

   @GET(URL)
   void getBirdList(Callback<List<Bird>> objectManager);
}
```

I want to write test code to test if the number of items in List is equal to 15(for example) after successful callback of getBirdList() as shown is MainActivity.java . Also,  I am using Robolectric and Mockito library for testing. I am trying to write since tuesday .please help.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you don't test that the actual request to server is working, due to the server response might change and you may not have internet when running test, but test it with some mock data.

Here is an example where he's using mockito together with retrofit to unit-test api functionality:

http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2013/12/16/reliable-android-http-testing-with-retrofit-and-mockito.html

Good luck!

Comment: I have already seen this link.The way he has implemented retrofit code is different from mine(for example He is using setApi() which i am not ,this setApi() is playing a crucial role in writing test code) . Unfortunately , I am not able to write test code with mock data too. Please help if you can write a test code with mock data .Thank you.